# How do you validate a GraphQL mutation in Python

Tags: python, graphql

I am new to GraphQL. I am using [Graphene-Django](http://docs.graphene-python.org/projects/django/en/latest/) and have a mutation called `CreateUser`. It takes three arguments `username`, `email`, `password`.

How do I validate the data and return multiple errors back?

I want something like this returned.

```
{  
   "name":[  
      "Ensure this field has at least 2 characters."
   ],
   "email":[  
      "This field may not be blank."
   ],
   "password":[  
      "This field may not be blank."
   ]
}
```

So I can render the errors on the form like this:

[image]

My code so far:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User as UserModel
from graphene_django import DjangoObjectType
import graphene


class User(DjangoObjectType):
    class Meta:
        model = UserModel
        only_fields = 'id', 'username', 'email'


class Query(graphene.ObjectType):
    users = graphene.List(User)
    user = graphene.Field(User, id=graphene.Int())

    def resolve_users(self, info):
        return UserModel.objects.all()

    def resolve_user(self, info, **kwargs):
        try:
            return UserModel.objects.get(id=kwargs['id'])
        except (UserModel.DoesNotExist, KeyError):
            return None


class CreateUser(graphene.Mutation):

    class Arguments:
        username = graphene.String()
        email = graphene.String()
        password = graphene.String()

    user = graphene.Field(User)

    def mutate(self, info, username, email, password):
        user = UserModel.objects.create_user(username=username, email=email, password=password)
        return CreateUser(user=user)


class Mutation(graphene.ObjectType):
    create_user = CreateUser.Field()


schema = graphene.Schema(query=Query, mutation=Mutation)
```

Comment: Hi, I was looking for something similar too and came up with a small PoC to have Django Rest Framework like validation on Graphene: https://github.com/chpmrc/graphene-validator. Feel free to try it out, feedback is more than welcome!

Not posting as an answer since it's not ready for release yet.

Comment: @MarcoChiappetta do you use this with GraphQL Code Generator / Formik / Yup? I'm new to this stack, but would your validator weave into that? Can you point to any articles/docs that use that full stack? There doesn't seem to be a lot of docs going from Graphene to the front end forms.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Model errors in the schema, primarily by using unions.

In SDL format:

```
type RegisterUserSuccess {
  user: User!
}

type FieldError {
  fieldName: String!
  errors: [String!]!
}

type RegisterUserError {
  fieldErrors: [FieldError!]!
  nonFieldErrors: [String!]!
}


union RegisterUserPayload = RegisterUserSuccess | RegisterUserError

mutation {
  registerUser(name: String, email: String, password: String): RegisterUserPayload!
}
```